# How to connect in Python 3.7 to a hadoop/hive database (that requires authentication) and execute a simple SQL query?

Tags: sql, python-3.x, hadoop, hive

I need to connect to a hadoop (apache hive) database that requires authentication with user/password.
I normally access it with DBeaver (JDBC drivers installed) but now I need to retrieve data using a simple query with a script in Python 3.7 (not Python 2.x).
I tried several methods without success.
Does someone have a solution that works?

I tried pyhive, presto, pyhs2, impala, ibis

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can follow below steps for connecting hive from python by ODBC driver on windows machine,

> 1. Install required driver for Hive. If you are using Cloudera/Hortonworks you can find respective drivers on their website.
> 2. Once installation done, go to **64-bit ODBC Administrator** from startup menu or control panel.
> 3. Fill required server details and connection user id and password. Below is screen shot for same.

[image]

> 1. Once that is done check test connection by clicking on Test button, and check if it is successful or not.
> 2. You can use same DSN while connecting hive from python, below is code snippet for same.

```py
    import pyodbc
    
    import pandas as pd
    
    with pyodbc.connect("DSN=<replace DSN name>", autocommit=True) as conn:
        df = pd.read_sql("<Hive Query>", conn)
```

Answer (score 4):

@ASK many thanks!

Following your suggestion, I created the DSN and was able to connect and read the table using the following code:

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd

table = "table_name"
query = 'SELECT * FROM {0}'.format(table)

with pyodbc.connect("DSN=Hive_connection",autocommit=True) as conn:
    df=pd.read_sql_query(query,conn)
```