# How will setting autocommit = True affect queries from python to Hive server when calling pyodbc.connect()

Tags: python, pandas, hive, pyodbc

I am trying to connect a jupyter notebook I'm running in a `conda` environment to a **Hadoop cluster** through **Apache Hive** on **cloudera**. I understand from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54363369/how-to-connect-in-python-3-7-to-a-hadoop-hive-database-that-requires-authentica) that I should install/set up the **cloudera odbc driver** and use `pydobc` and with a connection as follows:

```py
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd
    
with pyodbc.connect("DSN=<replace DSN name>", autocommit=True) as conn:
    df = pd.read_sql("<Hive Query>", conn)
```

My question is about the autocommit parameter. I see in the [pyodbc connection documentation](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Connection) that setting autocommit to True will make it so that I don't have to explicitly commit transactions, but it doesn't specify what that actually means.

What exactly is a transaction ?
I want to select data from the hive server using `pd.read_sql_query()` but I don't want to make any changes to the actual data on the server.

*Apologies if this question is formatted incorrectly or if there are (seemingly simple) details I'm overlooking in my question - this is my first time posting on stackoverflow and I'm new to working with cloudera / Hive.*

I haven't tried connecting yet or running any queries yet because I don't want to mess up anything on the server.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Ideally, you use pyspark + koalas here rather than pyodbc

Answer (score 1):

Hive do not have concept of commit and starting transactions like RDBMS systems.

You should not worry about autocommit.